# In need of a different obj-c indentation (Emacs)

Tags: objective-c, emacs

I'm using Emacs for some obj-c programming, and I'm having a really hard time with the default indentation scheme. I don't know enough list or emacs lisp to fix this myself, but hopefully someone out here might be able to lend a helping hand.

Here's an example of how I would like my code to be indented:

```
void someFunc() {
    NSBitmapImageRep* repout = [
        [NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
        initWithBitmapDataPlanes: NULL
        pixelsWide: width
        pixelsHigh: height
        bitsPerSample: 8
        samplesPerPixel: 4
        hasAlpha: YES
        isPlanar: NO
        colorSpaceName: NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
        bytesPerRow: width*4
        bitsPerPixel: 32
    ];
}
```

Yet here's what M-x indent-region currently does, it's quite gruesome:

```
void someFunc() {
    NSBitmapImageRep* repout = [
        [NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                                   initWithBitmapDataPlanes: NULL
                                                 pixelsWide: width
                                                 pixelsHigh: height
                                              bitsPerSample: 8
                                            samplesPerPixel: 4
                                                   hasAlpha: YES
                                                   isPlanar: NO
                                             colorSpaceName: NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                                                bytesPerRow: width*4
                                               bitsPerPixel: 32
        ];
}
```

I don't so much care bout having things line up on the colons as I do having them line up on the first letters. Also, it clearly indents the argument list way too far in. Lastly, it puts the closing "];" one indentation level too deep.

Many thanks in advance to any emacs config hackers who might post responses.

-Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You may change the indentation of the different syntactic elements by calling `c-set-offset`.  If you call it interactively, emacs will tell you the value of the "indentation variable" you want to change, and will ask you for a value.

Programatically, this would do something close to what you want in the example you mention, but you may have many other use cases where you want another behavior:

```
(c-set-offset 'arglist-intro '+)
(c-set-offset 'arglist-close 0)
(c-set-offset 'objc-method-call-cont 'c-lineup-argcont)
```